# Trying to compare an array item to a useres input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to replace an object in an array if the user inputs the letter E/e. For example the array can contain 2 objects the first object in the array the user entered a 3, the user now inputs a 5 e, they new array object [0] becomes the new user input 5. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab1a {
    public static void main (String argv []) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance ();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits (2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits (2);

    String inputValue;
    double [] doubleValues = new double [1];
    char char1, char2, char3;

    inputValue = stdin.readLine ();
    String [] Values2 = inputValue.split ("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < Values2.length; ++i)
        doubleValues [i] = Double.parseDouble (Values2[i]);

    double old = doubleValues[0];

    double newNum = doubleValues[1];

    //Line 3: 3 characters separated by spaces 
    inputValue = stdin.readLine ();
    String [] Values3 = inputValue.split ("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < Values3.length; ++i);
    char1 = Values3[0].charAt(0);
    char2 = Values3[1].charAt(0);
    char3 = Values3[2].charAt(0);

    if (inputValues == 'double' + "e") {
        System.out.println(old);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a specific question.

Comment: Your last for loop is just looping through without doing anything. Get rid of `;` after your loop.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Explain with sample input output

Comment: @MixMedia:  double newNum = doubleValues[1]; will throw an OutOfBounds Exception since you initialized the doubleValues to size 1 thus the only available index is [0]

Answer (score 0):

so I whipped this up fairly quickly and it answers your posted question. 
It initializes your array to a fixed SIZE=10 and asks user for input till 'q' is entered.
if user enters 'digit e/E' then the last entered value will be replaced.

Hope that helps!
cheers!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1a {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE =10;//SIZE of array, you can change that if you want to
    int availableIndex =0;//available element to change
    double [] values = new double [SIZE];


    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    while(availableIndex < values.length){
        System.out.println("Please enter a value, if you wish to modify the last input value, then please enter your new value followed by an E/e");
        System.out.println("enter q to exit");
        String input = kb.nextLine().trim();     
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))System.exit(0);
        String [] arr = input.split("\\s+");
        //for (String s : arr)System.out.println(s);
        //validate input 
        if (arr.length == 1){//no change requested
            values [availableIndex++] = Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
        }
        else{
            if (arr[1].equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                values[(availableIndex-1)] = Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);//availableIndex++;
            }
            else{//user inputed a char other than e/E
                values[availableIndex++]= Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
            }
        }

        //print contents
        for (int i=0; i < availableIndex; i++){
            System.out.print(values[i]+"; ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: FYI: there are no exception handling, code assumes that user will input: a {value}, or {value}SPACE{e/E}, or {q}